# Going to a non-Schengen country while waiting for the first residence permit

Tags: schengen, italy

I recently moved to Italy for work (4 months ago) and I have applied for my first residence permit. I still have not received my residence permit.

I also have a MULTI visit D visa valid for another 6 months. Due to some unforeseen circumstances, I have to go to my home country. I have the receipt from the post office.

Can I go and comeback without any issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Since your D visa is still valid, you can use it to enter the Schengen area when you return from your trip.  If you cannot return until after it expires, though, things get complicated; in that case you would probably need to apply for a new visa while you are in your home country.